# Can you put JFrames inside Full Screen Exclusive Mode?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

To be honest, I didn't quite know how to express my question in the title. So if someone has a clearer idea of what i'm trying to ask, then please be so kind as to edit it, for the greater good of mankind.

I have the following code:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Window window = new Window(frame);

    JButton btn = new JButton("Quit");
    window.add(btn);

    if(gd.isFullScreenSupported())
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(window);

    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }
    });
}
```

}

What I want to do is make a library system, illustrated in full screen mode. Inside the full screen mode, there should be simple frame windows with text fields in them and so on... No heavy 2D/3D graphics required here...

My problem is, the quit button is resized to fit the entire screen. I've tried to use setBounds, setSize, etc, on the frame, window and even button... But it doesn't seem to let me be able to center the button in the middle.

So my question: Is it possible to make JFrame application windows inside a JFrame application window which is set to full screen exclusive mode? Or is it only possible to use full screen exclusive mode together with 2D/3D methods like drawing?

Note: The only thing I intend to use full screen mode for is to set it to a black background, and have a Jframe window ontop of this black background in the center of the application. It is to give the illusion that the application is actually a system.

Thank you.

P.S. please note that the quit button was merely for my own testing purposes. It won't be part of the actual system, so my question does not revolve around how to resize this particular quit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fullscreen Exclusive Mode is not meant to have Swing components inside. It is meant as a high performance way to draw graphics in Java (and can benefit as much as possible of underlaying hardware if done right).

What you want to do could be done by using an undecorated [JDesktopPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html) and maximize it over the dimensions of the screen. Then proceed with using a [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) to have a JFrame like window inside that JDesktopPane.

I've included links to the respective API sections, they should get you started.

Comment: This MDI stuff is exactly what I was looking for... I think it is possible for me to combine MDI with Full-Screen Exclusive Mode to achieve what I want, instead of maximizing the dimensions of the JDesktopPane. Thank you alot mate.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are after is an MDI Application. If that is what you are after you could take a look [here](http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/creating-mdi-applications-in-java-using-netbeans/).

Comment: Big thanks mate. This, together with what Falx wrote, is really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you do not use layout manager correctly. 
Learn about layout managers - the modules that put and size/resize the visual components on screen. Then decide how do you want your button to look like and then decide which layout manager to use. It will do its job.

Comment: Would that make it possible to have new JFrame windows inside the JFrame window which is full screened?

Answer (score 0):

You know what i also had the exact same problem and the only thing i know from my experience is that you can use jinternal frame and set its property undecorated to true then add your custom title bar according to your requirement.