# Full Screen Exclusive Mode

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen

I want to implement full screen exclusive mode in my already made program, my main class is freeTTS.java which is:

```
package freetts;

public class FreeTTS {

public static void main(String[] args) {


   new FormTTS().setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

The other code of the whole program is in FormTTS.java which is a subclass of JFrame.

I tried to put the code to make it full screen in here but it gave all sorts of different errors, Do I have to put the code in FreeTTS or FormTTS?

Here is my file struct: (Note: FormTTS is another java file)
[image]

See i want to remove the pinkish whole border:
[image]

Comment: What is FormTTS? A subclass of JFrame?

Comment: It is another java file

Comment: Is it a `JFrame` component? If yes then try `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`

Comment: @Braj no it is another java file

Comment: What is another? Please share code that is most important.

Comment: Most classes are from another Java file. What we mean is, you've called 'setVisible' and so it's probably a subclass of a swing Component of some description. We need to know what it is a subclass of before we can help.

Comment: what do you want to do. is your program using Swing components is what people are asking basically.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1816aa699885ae4d5670 is FormTTS.java

Comment: Okay, it's a JFrame subclass. Gotcha.

Comment: What is Exclusive mode?

Comment: @Braj Have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html

Comment: Find it here [Can you put JFrames inside Full Screen Exclusive Mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428517/can-you-put-jframes-inside-full-screen-exclusive-mode)

Comment: @Braj I did not get that, i could not understand it :( Could you pls tell me how to do that?

Comment: Read it again. What you want to do could be done by using an undecorated JDesktopPane and maximize it over the dimensions of the screen. Then proceed with using a JInternalFrame to have a JFrame like window inside that JDesktopPane.

Comment: Did you got it? Use JDesktopPane and maximize it over the dimensions of the screen.

Comment: @Braj The thing is that I am new to java, i have made the whole prg mostly through netbeans gui and i do not know what these terms even mean, i want to do something which can make my existing prg go full screen. What i could make out from this tells me that i have to make new frames and all and i could not do it in my existing prg

Comment: What is a "JDesktopPane" and if i maximize it won't the borders still come?

Comment: Read [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). Find sample code on Google or try [http://way2java.com/swing/jdesktoppane/](http://way2java.com/swing/jdesktoppane/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22741043/2587435), The answer may have been incompatible with the netbeans GUI builder formatting and with your program design, So here is an example that may be more compatible. Try it out and see what happens.

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FormTTS extends JFrame {
    private boolean isFullScreen = false;
    private JButton button;

    public FormTTS() {
        initComponents();
        initFullScreen();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        button = new JButton(
                "I'm a smallbutton in a Huge Frame, what the heck?!");
        add(button);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initFullScreen() {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        isFullScreen = device.isFullScreenSupported();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(isFullScreen);
        setResizable(!isFullScreen);
        if (isFullScreen) {
            // Full-screen mode
            device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
            validate();
        } else {
            // Windowed mode
            this.pack();
            this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FormTTS().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @peeskilllet I do have to put the code in freetts right? and how do i put this code in it?

Comment: I can see that you have added buttons from the code, could you please tell a code which i can integrate into my program to check it out

Comment: You just need the boolean, and the method `initFullScreen()` .I just added the button, so the frame would have something. `initComonents()` is the autogenerated code

Comment: Does this have to go in freetts.java or formtts.java? From the code i assume formtts but my main class is freetts

Comment: I Just tested it with a `JFrame` form, and I get a `IllegalComponentStateException`. It's because of the `setUndecorated`. I has to be called before `pack()`. But `pack()` is in the auto-generated code. I'm trying to figure it out. If you comment out the `setUndecorated`, It'll work, but you will see the frame. Give me a bit to try and figure it out.

Comment: All your classes are frames, so _all_ of them (that are frames). You need to do it for every frame.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, FreeTTS is the launching class. You need the code in FormTTS (which is the frame)

Comment: i ll just try dat once

Comment: Ok So The only solution I can think of (and tested) is to put the `setUndecorated(true)` _before_ the `initComponents()` and get rid of it inside `initFullFrame()`. It works for me

Comment: There is still a problem, i see the taskbar

Comment: Do this. Open a whole new program to test it out, because I don't know what you're doing wrong. 1) Open a new JFrame form. 2) Add my boolean field. 3) add the `initFullScreen` method (without the setUndecorated). 4) Put the `setUndecorated(true)` _before_ the `initComonents()`. 5) call `initFullScreen()` after `initComponent()`. If you just do that (which is what I did to test), it _should_ work. Then you cna debug your program, if it works for you also.

Comment: @DakshShah - You have a bounty open this program in a different question. Get peeskillet to answer there and you should really award him that bounty if he has solved your problem. It may still be in it's grace period.

Comment: @Rudi I've looked at that question and I don't think it's related.

Comment: @peeskillet Why do u think it is not related? I am really getting confused here... y is it not related?

Comment: @Rudi because the problem was not how to set the full screen, but why the views look like that in full screen

Comment: @DakshShah Sorry, the previous comment was for you.. Am I wrong about that? (The comment I mean, about it not being related/solving the problem)

Comment: @peeskillet No you understood something else, in the question there my main point is just how to go to full screen and work even if i put it on lcd (changed resolution)

Comment: @DakshShah Did using the Full-Screen mode solve that problem for you though?

Comment: @peeskillet I did not try that yet, i think i will have to change the background into an image and then try, I will try,....

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to do the following, although I recommend having a read of the official [guide on fullscreen exclusive mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html).

```
FormTTS ftts = new FormTTS();

GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
gd.setFullScreenWindow(ftts);

ftts.setUndecorated(true);
ftts.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Where to add this? In main?

Comment: @DakshShah - Yep, just replace it with what you have in main now. I really do recommend having a read of the guide though, because there is usually a little more to it than this.

Comment: I can still see the borders :(

Comment: Still there are borders

Comment: @DakshShah - In which case, you will need to call setUndecorate(true). I've added that into the answer.

Comment: I have added that statement, but still i can see the borders

Comment: What kind of borders? You mean the bar at the top with the minimise, maximise and exit button?

Comment: just a sec, i will upload a snip of it

Comment: Without seeing the full code I probably can't help you then. It's likely that it has something to do with how the `JFrame` itself and it's subcomponents are laid out. I can't help but feel there is probably a call to `.pack();` in there somewhere undoing the fullscreen mode.

Comment: Can you look through the code once? I shared a link earlier having my code

Comment: @DakshShah - With  only a quick glance over it, I noticed that you've instantiate a JFrame inside FormTTS and set it's properties when FormTTS is itself a JFrame. A very odd thing to do. If you replace any instances of `Menu` with `this`, then the code may work. But it would take a lot of time to debug that sufficiently to know for sure. You don't need to create a new JFrame instance in initComponent() because when init component runs in the constructor your running the code in an existing instance of a JFrame subclass.

Comment: I added setundecorated true b4 initcomponents in formtts and it takes me to full screen but the only problem left is that i still see the task

Comment: @DakshShah - updated my answer with something to try.

Comment: It gives me an error saying Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.
 at java.awt.Frame.setUndecorated(Frame.java:923)
 at freetts.FormTTS.<init>(FormTTS.java:93)
 at freetts.FreeTTS.main(FreeTTS.java:59)

Comment: No problem, dont feel silly i followed what peeskillet said and i am able to do it for other jframes, now i ll try to debug on my own

Comment: @DakshShah - No problem. Something to looks at, your instantiating a new `JFrame` called `Menu` in your FormTTS class, but that doesn't need to happen. You should really be using `this` as your `JFrame`.

Comment: Menu is another jFrame, in `this` i have login screen and in `menu` i have the menu

Comment: @DakshShah Ah, okay. Just so you know, it's generally good practice to only use 1 `JFrame` in an application, and use `JDialog` for any extra windows you need. But I don't imagine that matters now.

Comment: No it does matter, i have to make the whole application again cauz i have made a hell lot of mistakes i have 10-15 java files each having a main class and 2-3 jframes in each of them